# Enabled/disabled mod menu options should be more visibly distinguished

Tags: bug, design, moderator-tools, accessibility, mac

Moderators get a menu of things we can do to questions. Some that aren't applicable will be disabled. There's a problem: depending on one's browser and OS it's nearly impossible to tell what's enabled and what isn't.

See Chrome (left) and Firefox (right) on MacOS for example:

[image]
[image]

Other users have an easier time telling enabled and disabled apart because of their browser and OS. This screenshot depicts Firefox on Windows:

[image]

Could the enabled and disabled fields be more clearly distinguished please? For example, **fade out the text** on disabled options.

Comment: It's not Mac-specific. I see the same thing on Windows. Why did you add the [[tag:mac]] tag, @Shog9?

Comment: It's apparently a much bigger problem on Macs, at least going by screenshots. A fix here would improve the experience everywhere though.